# What does the phrase 'wrapped up' mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

I am reading the book about the Simpsons, and I am stuck on this part of the text:

'The Simpsons had long produced finely crafted storytelling **that gave each of an episode’s principal characters something to do and wrapped up every plot thread**. Those elements were left by the wayside in several Season 9 episodes, mostly as a way to skip over plot holes and cram characters into bizarre situations.'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To wrap something up means to conclude it. The author means to say that each sub plot was given a conclusion. He/she seems to suggest in season 9 that several episodes left sub plots unfinished.